# How to load list of audio files from server inside list-view in android

Tags: php, android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I am trying to get all audio files from particular folder from my server to list-view. What i want to do is i have several audio files located in my server

`http://server-link/folder-name/all-audio-file.mp4`

So i want to load all this file inside my list-view and when i click on any particular audio it should play that audio files.

I have done this things with SD-card that it will load all audio from SD-card to list-view and when i click on it, it plays that audio but i don't know how to load audio from server.

So please can anyone guide me how can i do this or any sample code or application will help more.

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried to far? Displaying entries from the SD Card and a URL aren't all that different. The only difficulty would be pulling down the list from the server. Is that the part you are having difficulty with?

Comment: @WilliamSeemann, Sorry for late reply, Yes exactly same thing i am looking for that how to pull the list of audio or video from server to list-view.